# Rambam Mishneh Torah handbook

Tags: product-recommendation, rambam, mishneh-torah

Rambam’s Mishneh Torah is filled with particular words and phrases used repeatedly. It’s also organized in a very particular fashion. Both the word choice and the structure are used deliberately. However, traversing through the Mishneh Torah itself, one can sense that he’s missing why Rambam is using this particular phrase or structuring it in that particular way but it’s unclear why.

Is there a book or essay perhaps that serves as a sort of handbook to understand why Rambam wrote what he wrote?

Comment: Typically mimics the underlying source material

Comment: "Is there a book or essay perhaps that serves as a sort of handbook to understand why rambam wrote what he wrote?" There are centuries of such books. If you're looking for the classics, check out the nose kelim traditionally printed alongside the MT and for something more modern explore R. Nahum Rabinovitch's Yad Peshutah and R. Yosef Qafih's commentary... unless I misunderstand your intent, in which case your question may need some more details/clarity.

Comment: This question seems very unclear to me. "one can sense that he's missing..." Examples would be helpful.

Comment: Yes, it's called Mishna, Gemara and Midrash. He uses the same unique phrases as the Oral Tradition that he is encapsulating in the referenced work

Answer (score 0):

Nice question, I never came across such a book in English but it would be useful.

What you might find useful is to learn one topic in depth, from its sources in the mishna and gemara to the Rambam. You will see how the Rambam's language or cases often come straight from the sources he used. The Migdal Oz commentary (on the pages of a traditional Hebrew Rambam) gives the relevant references, and Sefaria does the same online.

In parallel, you might want to check

- The Rambam's own [introduction to Mishneh Torah](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/901656/jewish/Introduction-to-Mishneh-Torah.htm)
- R Yosef Kapach's [introduction to his edition of the Mishneh Torah](https://mhcny.org/pdf/Introduction%20to%20Mishneh%20Torah.pdf)
- a [review](https://hakirah.org/Vol%2012%20Feintuch.pdf) of R Nachum Rabinovitch’s introduction to his commentary to Mishneh Torah, *Yad haPeshuta*
- a more academic debate on the structure of the MT in the pages of Hakirah ([here](https://hakirah.org/Vol19Kaplan.pdf) and [there](https://hakirah.org/vol21Gillis.pdf))

I look forward to more relevant works being surfaced by the MY community.

Comment: I have been searching for quite some time to get a complete set of Rav Kapach's edition of the Mishneh Torah. It has been out of print for several years. Do you know anywhere, by chance? While on that subject, I'm also looking for a complete Torah Shleimah by Rabbi Menachem Kasher. That has also been out of print for years.

Comment: @YaacovDeane I have a set of R. Qafih's MT that I ordered from Israel, you can get it here: https://www.net-sah.org/library/770 the office manager's name is ורד בדיחי she is very helpful and accommodating. As for R. Kasher's work... I've been looking for a set too lol... came very close a few years ago getting a used set but someone managed to snag it before me.